# How to get rid of this warning message

Tags: r, multiprocessing

When I just open the Rstudio and press entre on the Console, it always give me the warning message

```
> 
Warning message:
In .recacheSubclasses(def@className, def, env) :
  undefined subclass "numericVector" of class "Mnumeric"; definition not updated
>
```

How to get rid of this warning message?

Thank you!

I previously ran `boot::boot()` function using multicore processing, and after that when I start Rstudio and run the first command, the warning message always appears.

Comment: Are your R packages up-to-date? See this: https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/issues/2116

Comment: I have updated all related packages, the warning message still appears when I start rstudio and run the first command. Just the first command, the second command has no warning message.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Update R to the newest version [[click here]](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/)
2. Re-install the **boot** package of whatever packages that face this warning. I suggest the following code for that:

   `remove.packages('boot')`

   `install.packages('boot', dependencies=T)`

   `library(boot)`
3. Restart your R or Rstudio and try to use your function again. If it bothers you again, you can ignore it using `options(warn=-1)`.

Best of Luck.